# Pygame drawing within a class

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a ping pong game in pygame and trying to draw the paddles and a ball within a class.

When I attempt to draw it within a normal function it works fine, but when I try to implement it with a class I get a load of errors.

What am I doing wrong? Would it just be easier for me to create an image in photoshop and import it? Also, do I draw the paddles within the **init** method or a separate method.

Here's my code, the class is in a separate file.

paddles.py:

```
import pygame    
import sys
class Paddles():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.paddle_l = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [15, 250, 10, 100])
        self.paddle_r = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [780, 250, 10, 100])
```

program.py:

```
 import sys
 import pygame

 from settings import Settings
 from paddles import Paddles
 import game_functions as gf


 def run_game():
     # Initialise pygame, settings and screen object.
     pygame.init()
     ai_settings = Settings()
     screen =     pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
     pygame.display.set_caption('Ping Pong')

     #Make paddles
     paddles = Paddles(screen)
     paddles.paddles()

     # Start the main loop for the game.
     while True:
         gf.check_events()
         gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen,paddles)


 run_game()
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pingpong/.idea/program.py", line 27, in <module>
    run_game()   
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pingpong/.idea/program.py", line 19, in run_game
    paddles.paddles() 
AttributeError: 'Paddles' object has no attribute 'paddles'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you edit your question to include the error messages you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, just added.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening on a line in `run_game` that reads `paddles.paddles()`, but I don't see any line like that in your question. Is this the most up-to-date code?

Comment: paddles.Paddles() didn't show up on the post for some reason. Now fixed. The pygame window opens for a second then closes.

Comment: Hi Rehann, I have also had similar problems when refactoring games when using PyGame.  I think to emulate what you are getting AND find something that works (not the objective of these questions but often done by a helpful community) one would need all the code to go through it.  I found the following site extremely useful to get to griips with PyGame and also to learn how to use Sprites- hopefully it will give you some new ideas and some deeper knowledge of how to work with PyGame.  

http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code

Best of luck!

Comment: @srattigan Will definitely look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just as it says in the error message, your `Paddle` class has no function named `paddles`. Your class should look like:

```
class Paddles():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.paddle_l = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [15, 250, 10, 100])
        self.paddle_r = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [780, 250, 10, 100])

    def paddles(self):
        # DO STUFF WITH PADDLES
```

I'm not entirely sure what you intend this function to do, but that's up to you.

Comment: Is my __init__ function correct? How do i get the paddles to actually show on screen?

Comment: @Rehaan yup I believe the init function is correct. You should just omit the line `paddles.paddles()` and I believe you should get your paddles

Comment: ok so it now runs without any errors but the paddles aren't showing up. Could it be that the screen background colour is overwriting the paddles?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting it's because you're trying to use a method from `Paddles` which would be `paddles`, but it doesn't exist.

Your file, for what I got, is called `paddles.py` (I can guess for your code), so it doesn't mean your class `Paddles` has this `paddles` method.

To fix it, just add the `paddles` method inside your `Paddles` class, such as:

```
import pygame    
import sys

class Paddles():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.paddle_l = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [15, 250, 10, 100])
        self.paddle_r = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [780, 250, 10, 100])
    def paddles():
        # Method operations
```

Comment: I've removed paddles.paddles() so the code now runs without any errors but now the paddles aren't showing up. Is the screen background colour overwriting the paddles?

Comment: @user9354162, if you changed your class to include the `paddles` method, the way I mentioned, you should not omit or exclude the line `paddles.paddles()`, as it won't be executed if you do so. 
Keep this line, but it'll only work if you add the `paddles` method inside your function `Paddles`